# Встраивание готового приложения на WinForms на форму

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Возможно ли встроить готовое приложение (приложение 1) в контейнер/саму форму другого приложения (приложения 2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только если это приложение поддерживает OLE Automation (ActiveX)

Comment: Приложение 1 или приложение 2?

Comment: @Rubikoid: приложение 1

Answer (score 1):

С помощью функции [SetParent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633541%28vs.85%29.aspx) можно **показать** показать одно приложение внутри другого. А как **управлять** им - другой вопрос.